# Generate Swagger documentation server in Go from Swagger/OpenAPI specification

Tags: go, swagger, openapi, go-gin

I have an OpenAPI specification and I have used `openapi-generator` to generate Golang `gin` server.

What is the conventional way to generate Swagger documentation server from the OpenAPI specification?

I have already tried [swag](https://github.com/swaggo/swag): it generates documentation on http://localhost:8080/swagger/index.html endpoint. But this requires API to be described in code annotations. I am looking for a Swagger UI generator from the OpenAPI specification that I already have.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "swagger interface from the open API spec"? Swagger is the old 2.0 name for OpenAPI. OpenAPI is used for version 3.0 onward.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Gin, but I am happy to share my solution (based upon go-server):

1. Create a directory in your project root dir called ./swagger-ui
2. Copy the files under `dist/*` of swagger-ui (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) here
3. Update in `swagger-ui/index.html` the location of the api spec to `url: "/api/openapi.yaml"`
4. In `main.go` create a new variable annotated with `//go:embed swagger-ui/* api/openapi.yaml` (the latter directory was created by openapi-generator CLI)
5. Add below the (generated) router in `main.go`: `router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.FS(staticFiles)))`

That's it - you will have the Swagger UI available under /swagger-ui and the api definition loaded automatically from /api/openapi.yaml

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    ...
)

//go:embed swagger-ui/* api/openapi.yaml
var staticFiles embed.FS

func main() {
    router := ....

    // Embed the Swagger UI within Go binary
    router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.FS(staticFiles)))

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run swagger editor in a docker container. Pull it from https://hub.docker.com/r/swaggerapi/swagger-editor, run it, point your browser at http://localhost:8080, then load your api.yaml file. You can also run swagger ui https://hub.docker.com/r/swaggerapi/swagger-ui.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that packages Swagger UI as Go `http.Handler`: https://github.com/swaggest/swgui.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/swaggest/swgui/v3emb" // For go1.16 or later.
    // "github.com/swaggest/swgui/v3" // For go1.15 and below.
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", v3.NewHandler("My API", "/swagger.json", "/"))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

`"/swagger.json"` in this example is an URL to the OpenAPI spec file.